Why is my model jumping around all over the place?
Every time it gets to that position it goes crazy, I'm not sure why.  It's weird that the box is bobbing up and down as well.  It's just supposed to be a simple pendulum / slider mechanism.  URDF attached.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="PendulumModel_Simple">

  <material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
  </material>

  <link name="world" />
  <joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link="base_link" />
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

  <!-- base link to the rail -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
    </inertial>
    <kinematic value="1"/>
  </link>

  <joint name="base_link_to_rail" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="rail"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="rail">
    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
        <box size="3.3 0.2 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <box size="3.3 0.2 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="rail_to_slider" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="rail"/>
    <child link="slider"/>
    <origin xyz="-1.55 0.0 .15"/>
    <axis xyz="1.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <limit lower="0.0" upper="3.3" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="slider">
    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.2 0.2 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.2 0.2 0.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="slider_to_pin" type="continuous">
    <parent link="slider"/>
    <child link="pin"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.15" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <axis xyz="0.0 1.0 0.0"/>
    <!-- <limit lower="0.0" upper="0.0" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/> -->
  </joint>

  <link name="pin">
    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.5"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.25 0.0" rpy="1.5707 0.0 0.0"/>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.5"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.25 0.0" rpy="1.5707 0.0 0.0"/>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="pin_to_pendulum" type="fixed">
    <parent link="pin"/>
    <child link="pendulum"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.50 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="pendulum">
    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 0.05 0.8"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.4" rpy="0 0.0 0.0"/>
    </visual>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 0.05 0.8"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.4" rpy="0 0.0 0.0"/>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="pendulum_to_ball" type="fixed">
    <parent link="pendulum"/>
    <child link="ball"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 -0.8" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <limit lower="0.0" upper="0.0" effort="0.0" velocity="0.0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="ball">
    <visual name='visual'>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 -.1" rpy="0 0.0 0.0"/>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1e-3" iyz="0.0" izz="1e-3"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision name='collision'>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 -.1" rpy="0 0.0 0.0"/>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <!-- Gazebo Plugins and interfaces -->

  <gazebo reference="ball">
    <gravity>true</gravity>
    <sensor name="imu_sensor" type="imu">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>100</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
        <topicName>imu</topicName>
        <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
        <updateRateHZ>10.0</updateRateHZ>
        <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
        <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
        <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
        <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
        <initialOrientationAsReference>false</initialOrientationAsReference>
      </plugin>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

  <ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
      <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <joint name="rail_to_slider">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-10</param>
        <param name="max">10</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>
  </ros2_control>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
      <parameters>/home/user/Code/Pendulum/src/pendulums/config/velocity.yaml</parameters>
      <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
      <controller_manager_name>simulation_controller_manager</controller_manager_name>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <!-- other properties you want to define for the base link -->
    <kinematic> true </kinematic>
  </gazebo>


</robot>


```


can you post the inputs graph as well ?  Seems like inputs to slider are exploding at the end ?

Found out the problem.  I decreased the simulation step size from 0.01 to 0.001 and it's working like it should now.  Had to make a new world file and not use the default one that is loaded.
